# What is the center of every simple abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Simple group is that it is not trivial and subgroups of simple group must be improper and trivial.

So, every simple abelian group has trivial subgroup and improper subgroup.

So, I think center of every simple abelian group is trivial subgroup and abelian group itself.

But, My professor says that the center of every simple abelian group is improper subgroup, whole group itself.

So, I am confused whether trivial subgroup of simple abelian group is center or not.

Comment: The center of any abelian group is itself.

Comment: Being abelian means that multiplication is commutative; $gh = hg$ for all $h, g \in G$. Thus, the center of every abelian group is the entire group. The only simple abelian groups are cyclic, with prime order.

Comment: what about trivial subgroup {e} ? isnt it the center of simple abelian group?

Comment: What makes you say $\{e\}$ should be the center? Remember, simple groups have two normal subgroups: $\{e\}$, and the entire group.

Comment: I mean, I thought that there could be two centers. one is {e} and the other is entire group itself if abelian.

Comment: The center of a group $G$ is defined as all group elements that commute with every other group element. In symbols, $Z(G) = \{z \in G: zg = gz \text{ for all }g\in G\}.$

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, a simple group is a nontrivial group whose only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself. Now centre of a group is normal. Now for an abelian group the center of the group is the group itself. So, there is no confusion!!